# How to return 0 if null then import to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I've got a sql data like this

```
1 2m
2 3m
3 3m
6 6m
7 6m
```

I want to export and show it into datagridview.

```
1 2m
2 3m
3 3m
4 0m
5 0m
6 6m
7 6m
```

And here is my code:

```
private void laygio(string tenstore, string tenxuat)
{
    string conn = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=NCKHmoi;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connect;
    connect.Open();
    int stday = Convert.ToInt32(dst.Text);
    int stmonth = Convert.ToInt32(mst.Text);
    int styear = Convert.ToInt32(yst.Text);
    int sthour = Convert.ToInt32(hst.Text);
    int stminute = 0;
    int stsecond = 0;
    int eday = Convert.ToInt32(ded.Text);
    int emonth = Convert.ToInt32(med.Text);
    int eyear = Convert.ToInt32(yed.Text);
    int ehour = Convert.ToInt32(hed.Text);
    int eminute = 0;
    int esecond = 0;
    DateTime startday = new DateTime(styear, stmonth, stday, sthour, stminute, stsecond);
    DateTime endday = new DateTime(eyear, emonth, eday, ehour, eminute, esecond);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    DataColumn Col = new DataColumn("Thời gian", typeof(int));
    tbl.Columns.Add(Col);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    int i = 1;
    for (DateTime xday = startday; xday <= endday; xday += TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
    {
        int ngay = Convert.ToInt32(xday.Day.ToString());
        int thang = Convert.ToInt32(xday.Month.ToString());
        int nam = Convert.ToInt32(xday.Year.ToString());
        int gio = Convert.ToInt32(xday.Hour.ToString());
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = @"Select SoLieuGio.LLNuoc from SoLieuGio where SoLieuGio.GioID= (select Gio.GioID from Gio where (Gio.Gio = @Gio and Gio.NgayID= (select Ngay.NgayID from Ngay where (Ngay.Ngay=@Ngay and Ngay.ThangID= (select Thang.ThangID from Thang where (Thang.Thang = @Thang and Thang.NamID=(select Nam.NamID from Nam where  (Nam.Nam = @Nam and Nam.TramID=(select Tram.TramID from Tram Where (Tram.TenTram like @TenTram and Tram.TinhID=(select Tinh.TinhID from Tinh where  (Tinh.TenTinh like @TenTinh and Tinh.KhuVucID=(select KhuVuc.KhuVucID from KhuVuc where KhuVuc.Ten=@Ten)))))))))))))";
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gio", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = gio;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Ngay", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ngay;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Thang", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = thang;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Nam", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = nam;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Ten", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Đồng Bằng Bắc Bộ";
        command.Parameters.Add("@TenTinh", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TinhComboBoxEx.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TenTram", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TramComboBoxEx.Text;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(tbl);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = tbl;            
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
    command.Dispose();
    connect.Close();
}
```

The result of that code is:

1 2m
2 3m
3 3m
6 6m
7 6m

What need i fix to show it fully from 1 to 7.

Comment: what is your table structure???

Comment: the query is work, but i want it to show the value that not in the data. it mean i want to add to the datagridview the value 0 if in data don't have.

Comment: 1-7 is present in your database or not

Comment: 1 2m
2 3m
3 3m
4 null
5 null
6 6m
7 6m
Can u get result like this

Comment: this: `adapter.Fill(tbl); dataGridView2.DataSource = tbl;` makes no sense in a `for` loop

Comment: 1 2m 2 3m 3 3m 4 0m 5 0m 6 6m 7 6m
@Amit Singh

Comment: the code is work. but the result is not as i want. the result is
1 2m 2 3m 3 3m 6 6m 7 6m. but i want is 1 2m 2 3m 3 3m 4 0m 5 0m 6 6m 7 6m

Comment: what is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7?its serial number of any coumn in datyabae...if u can show ur table structure than it help a lot....ok....what db u r using now

Comment: SoLieuGio Struct is: SoLieuGio.Gio, SoLieuGio.GioID, SoLieuGio.GioIDID, SoLieuGio.LLMua. 1,2,3,6,7 is a value of SoLieuGio.Gio, 2m,3m,3m,6m,6m, í value of SoLieuGio.LLMua
Am i right if i change the query to:"IFNULL(query,0)"

Comment: i'm using sql server and c#

Comment: hard to understand....can u tell me struture of table from u r getting data...properly by edititng question....explain the both table struecture

Comment: what i understand one table u have i-7 and other table u have 2m 3m 3m 6m etc and u geting result by inner join right

Comment: @Amit I think the OP doesn't have 1-7. What they probably need to do is use `master..spt_values` and do a left join. Normally I'd help but the sql in the sample is a mess. All those subqueries should probably be just simple joins. Also the sql only selects one column and the op wants two. I'm guessing the partial series of 1-7 is probably in Ngay.Ngay but it's hard for me to tell since I don't know Vietnamese

Comment: @ConradFrix i think he have these bcz he is getting rersult 1 2m
2 3m
3 3m
6 6m
7 6m....but he in not explaing his table well so hard to help him....

Comment: both of them is in one table SoLieuGio. and 1,2,3,6,7 look like a time 1:00, 2:00,3:00,6:00,7:00. such as: at 1:00 i have a value 2m; at 2:00 i have value 3m....

Comment: I have a data from 1 to 7, but missing value of 4 and 5. i want to import the value fully from 1 to 7, i set the missing value is 0.but the code i give only show value 1,2,3,6,7.

Comment: means u have no entry of 4&5 in database...so for this u have to manupulate ur data tbl in front end.

Comment: if u want that it comes from db than u have to write store provedure for that using tsql.

Comment: yes. that right. but i don't know how to write it. i'm try to use sp but i can't. i 've tried to use query. but it doén't give me a fully value. can you help me. thank a lot

Comment: means u want to write store provedure not to modify in front end using c#

Comment: any way. sp is ok, code c# ok too. no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tally table `master..spt_values` to deal with missing items in your series.

You do this by left joining to your tables and coalesce your values.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE ATable
    ([Number] int, [value] varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO ATable
    ([Number], [value])
VALUES
    (1, '2m'),
    (2, '3m'),
    (3, '3m'),
    (6, '6m'),
    (7, '6m')
;
```

This

```
SELECT
  v.Number,
  COALESCE(ATable.Value, '0m') Value
FROM
  master..spt_values  v
  LEFT JOIN ATable
  ON v.Number = ATable.Number
WHERE
  v.Type = 'P'
  and v.Number > 0 and v.Number < 8
```

Will produce this value

```
| NUMBER | VALUE |
------------------
|      1 |    2m |
|      2 |    3m |
|      3 |    3m |
|      4 |    0m |
|      5 |    0m |
|      6 |    6m |
|      7 |    6m |
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d18bb/8)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing to do in this case I think is to check everytime if the current value is the sum of the previous value + 1

```
if (current != (previous + 1)
{
    //make new 4 0m or something
}
else
{
    //continue reading
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temporary table that will hold missing values and then join main table and temporary table.

This is how it could look like

```
create table #temp1
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    M varchar(4)
)
declare @count int
SET @count = 0

declare @max int
SET @max = 20

while @count < @max
begin
insert into #temp1 (M) values ('0m') 
SET @count = @count + 1
end

select * from #temp1

select (case M1.ID when null then T1.ID else M1.ID) as ID,
(case M1.M when null then T1.M else M1.ID) as TXT
from MainTable M1
join #temp1 T1
order by ID
```

Comment: so hard to understand it. maybe i'm not intelligent enought to understand. but. thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need a temp table since SQL Server provides `master..sptvalues` Also `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` is often used instead of `CASE WHEN NULL`